# In .NET 6 Minimal API, how to return a 403 with html/text content

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, minimal-apis

I am using .NET 6 minimal API.  I have following simplified code which may return a file, HTTP 304 (not modified), or HTTP 403 (forbidden).

```
app.MapGet("/download", (HttpContext httpContext) =>
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Hour > 0)
    {
        var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
        {
            Title = "403 Forbidden",
            Detail = "You are forbidden.  File can only be downloaded at midnight!",
            Status = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden,
            Instance = httpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl()
        };
        return Results.Problem(problemDetails);
    }

    string eTag = "my-etag";
    if (httpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("If-None-Match", out var cachedEtag) && cachedEtag.Equals(eTag))
    {
        return Results.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status304NotModified);
    }

    var entityTag = new EntityTagHeaderValue('"' + eTag + '"');
    return Results.File(@"c:\my.pdf", "application/pdf", entityTag: entityTag);

});
```

The above code works great.  However, how can I return a 403 response with text/HTML rather than JSON?

Current 403 response:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.3",
    "title": "403 Forbidden",
    "status": 403,
    "detail": "You are forbidden.  File can only be downloaded at midnight!",
    "instance": "https://localhost:7052/test"
}
```

Wanted 403 response:

```
<html>
  <body>
      You are forbidden.  File can only be downloaded at midnight!
  </body>
</html>
```

When I replace `return Results.Problem()` with following code,

```
return new ContentResult
{
    StatusCode = 403,
    ContentType = "text/html",
    Content = "You are forbidden.  File can only be downloaded at midnight!"
};
```

Compiler gives me following error.

- Error    CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
  'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IResult' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'.
  An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
- Error    CS1662  Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate
  type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly
  convertible to the delegate return type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Create a custom class that implements `IResult` like this:

```
class CustomHTMLResult : IResult
{
    private readonly string _htmlContent;
    public CustomHTMLResult(string htmlContent)
    {
        _htmlContent = htmlContent;
    }
    public async Task ExecuteAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
        httpContext.Response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Text.Html;
        httpContext.Response.ContentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(_htmlContent);
        await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(_htmlContent);
     }
}
```

and then just do:

```
return new CustomHTMLResult("<html>\r\n<body>\r\n <b>You are forbidden.</b>  File can only be downloaded at midnight!\r\n</body>\r\n</html>");
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively if you can upgrade to .NET 7+ then you can use [`Results.Text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.results.text?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-results-text(system-string-system-string-system-text-encoding-system-nullable((system-int32)))):

```
app.MapGet("/customres", (HttpContext httpContext, CancellationToken ct) =>
    Results.Text(content: "You are forbidden.  File can only be downloaded at midnight!",
        contentType: "text/html",
        statusCode: (int?)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden));
```

Or [`TypedResults.Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.typedresults.content?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-typedresults-content(system-string-system-string-system-text-encoding-system-nullable((system-int32)))):

```
app.MapGet("/customres", (HttpContext httpContext, CancellationToken ct) => 
  TypedResults.Content(content: "You are forbidden.  File can only be downloaded at midnight!",
    contentType: "text/html",
    statusCode: (int?)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden));
```